# Sorting files into custom sorting order

Tags: java, sorting

I am looking to implement a sort feature. I want to sort the files in File[] list in a custom format.

```
File newfile = new File("reports/Weekly/xyz");
File[] list = newfile.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(list, NameFileComparator.NAME_COMPARATOR);
```

The files appear in the following sequence based on the above code:

```
1. reports/Weekly/xyz/cmp.xlsx
2. reports/Weekly/xyz/bn-wk.xlsx
3. reports/Weekly/xyz/se-wk.xlsx
4. reports/Weekly/xyz/se-wk-yoy.xlsx
```

But i want it in a custom order. Meaning,

```
1. reports/Weekly/xyz/se-wk.xlsx
2. reports/Weekly/xyz/se-wk-yoy.xlsx 
3. reports/Weekly/xyz/bn-wk.xlsx
4. reports/Weekly/xyz/cmp.xlsx
```

How can I write a custom sort function to do this?

Comment: are you sure of the order ? `c` comes after `b` in my alphabeth.

Comment: @Conffusion yes, it has to be in the same order

Comment: Then you need to explain the order logic. What if there is a file starting with `d` or `t` ?

Comment: Is the condition only applies for b coming before c or you want fir other alphabet too?

Comment: @ashdas the condition applies for other alphabets as well. The names should not be either in the ascending or descending order, rather in a custom format.